# Задание ЕГЭ Pascal

Tags: pascal

Нужно ввести контрольное число R, которое будет произведение двух элементов и делится на 2 (не квадрат). Выдает ошибку "Встречено 'array', а ожидался оператор".

```
    a: array [1..N] of integer;     
    i, j, R, rez: integer; 
begin  
  readln (N);
  R := 0;
  rez :=0;
  a: array [1..N] of integer;  
  for i :=1 to N do
    readln (a[i]);
    readln (R);
    if (R mod 21 = 0) then
  begin
    i:=1;
    j:=2;
   while (rez=0)and(i<N) do
    begin
      while (rez=0) and (j<N+1) do
      begin
        if (a[i]*a[j] = R) then rez:=1;
         j:= j+1;
         i:= i+1;
      end;
    end; 
 end;
  if (rez=1) then
  write ('контроль пройден')
  else 
    write ('контроль не пройден');
end."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  i, j, R, rez, N: integer; 
begin
  ...
  rez :=0;
  // a: array [1..N] of integer;  
  for i :=1 to N do
```

Comment: Неизвестное имя 'N'